# How to write values from a "For" loop into cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet which calculates a lengths.
I have to iterate a start Value until 2 other Values are comparable.

Two problems:
1. No Value is written into Cell(9, 6)
2. The If function should return false but it's always jumping to "Exit For"

I fail with the syntax. I tried various stuff I found but I don't find my mistakes.

To #1 I tried calling the cell with Range().Value 
To #2 I tried If(Abs()) <= ...

```
Sub Berechnung()

Dim tolerance As Integer
Dim i As Integer

tolerance = 0.2

For i = 500 To 1 Step -0.5
    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(9, 6).Value2 = i

    If (Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(6, 31).Value2 - Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(6, 33).Value2) <= tolerance Then
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(6, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Exit For
    Else:
    End If

Next i

Debug.Print i
MsgBox "Wert wurde berechnet"
End Sub
```

Comment: You are always testing the same cells, is it the desired behavior?  The tolerance is a constant, so you could test simply make the test once and according to the test result set Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(9, 6).Value2  to 500 or 1.

Comment: @VincentG yes, it is a desired behavior. I'm looking for a number smaller than 500 for a calculation with changing variables. As I change my variables I will recalculate the worksheet and use the colour to highlight the state of the worksheet. (I have a reset button which chages it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problems**

1. You should be able to set the cell value directly without making a
   reference to `Value2`.
2. If the difference of the two cells is negative, the condition will return true. Something like this may work.
3. Variables `i` and `tolerance` should be a Doubles.

**Answer**

```
Sub Berechnung()

Dim tolerance As Double
Dim i As Double

tolerance = 0.2

For i = 500 To 1 Step -0.5
    Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(9, 6) = i

    If Abs(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(6, 31) - Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(6, 33)) <= tolerance Then
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(6, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Exit For
    Else:
    End If

Next i

Debug.Print i
MsgBox "Wert wurde berechnet"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly its still the same. Could it be that ```
Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(9, 6) = i
``` doesn't work if the cell isn't empty?

Comment: ok. #1. works.It still exits the for loop every iteration though.

Comment: Its working fine for me provided `AE6` and `AG6` are populated are populated on worksheet `Tabelle1` in this case. It should alkso be noted that the only thing changing in the for loop is cells F9?

Maybe set the condition up as a separate variable?

It's hard to tell what's going on without more information.

Comment: thanks a lot. I found my mistake. its supposed to be Cells(31, 6)... Oo.